# Bash one liner to compile, execute and echo return value?

Tags: c, linux, bash, unix, return-value

I'm not a bash whiz, so please excuse the simplistic nature of this question.

I want to compile, execute and echo the return values of my programs in one line in a Linux shell. Something like...

`~$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 program.c && ./a.out && echo $?`

These all work separately, and this of course works, too:

```
~$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 program.c && ./a.out
...
~$ echo $?
5
~$
```

It seems like the problem is knowing when/if `./a.out` was successful because `~$ ./a.out && echo $?` does not work, either!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&&` operator only executes the next command if the previous was successful.  Use `;` instead.

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 program.c && (./a.out ; echo $?)
```

The parentheses make it so `echo $?` doesn't happen if `gcc` fails.

Comment: Is there any reason why you chose parenthesis rather than curly braces? The [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping) says this creates a subshell, but why is this advantageous in this instance to just executing in the current shell?

Comment: @highphi: The braces require more typing.

Comment: Interesting...! I knew there was a problem regarding detection of a program's execution "success".

Answer (score 1):

```
$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 program.c && ./a.out ; echo $?
```

Should do it.  The semicolon just separates commands, so the echo will always happen